# Android: Start a new activity from menu item

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menu

I'm Trying to open a second screen for my application. The user have to click on a menu item and then the screen must open. But what i try it always just ignores the rule after the case statement.

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.OpenScreen:  startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondScreenActivity.class));;
                            break;
    }
    return true;
```

I've also added the activity to AndroidManifest.xml inside the  tag.

Any help will be apreciated

---

### Solution

I had the `finish()` in the constructor of the new class.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ? i can't get any problem here.

Comment: The Second sscreen won't open, it stay's at the first screen

Comment: does your app even gets to the `case:` block? try adding `Log.d(TAG, "smth");` to check if it gets there. perhaps you are using wrong id or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me your java code is correct and work for me that way.

However when I learned Android, when I came at the point of starting a new activity I faced the same problem as you, nothing was happening, without any error, simply not working.

In my case I forgot to add the activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Perhaps it is the same for you.

Your AndroidManifest file should contain somewhere something like that

```
<activity
    android:name=".SecondScreenActivity" >
</activity>
```

this tell the system that SecondScreenActivity exitst.

In
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html they say :

> All activities must be represented by  elements in the manifest file. Any that are not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be run.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.OpenScreen:  
            startActivity(new Intent(YourClass.this, SecondScreenActivity.class));
                           break;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping, i just found it, i had the finish() in the constructor off the new class. Stupid me :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't `return true` for `onOptionsItemSelected`.

call **super** method like this.

```
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

instead of **return true;**

Comment: well now i have

              public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.OpenScreen:  startActivity(new Intent(Screen1.this, Screen2.class));;
                 break;
            case R.id.test:     Toast.makeText(this, "works!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
            
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

and still no luck :(
The test works, but the OpenScreen does nothing